# Too many callouts 11 while testing using webservicemock interface

Tags: governorlimits, callout, webservicemock

i have written a test class for a controller in which one of the method makes a callout. This is one single invocation of external SAP webservice. But my debug log shows more than 10 invocation of the webservice but my code actually does not. I already wrote webservice mock implementation class. What could be the issue? If needed i can provide the entire source here.

**Source Code:**

Generated class from WSDL

```
//Generated by wsdl2apex

public class sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS {
    public class ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00_element {
        public String Dpi2Rtrvlastsaveddata;
        public sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbstDatarcrd01 DpistInpt;
        private String[] Dpi2Rtrvlastsaveddata_type_info = new String[]{'Dpi2Rtrvlastsaveddata','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] DpistInpt_type_info = new String[]{'DpistInpt','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style','false','true'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'Dpi2Rtrvlastsaveddata','DpistInpt'};
    }
    public class Z_GSSMWFM_HNDL_EVNTRQST00 {
        //public String endpoint_x = 'http://xxxnj1:8050/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/z_gssmwfm_hndl_evntrqst00/110/z_gssmwfm_hndl_evntrqst00/z_gssmwfm_hndl_evntrqst00';
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://xx.xx.xxx.10:8050/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/z_gssmwfm_hndl_evntrqst00/110/z_gssmwfm_hndl_evntrqst00/z_gssmwfm_hndl_evntrqst00';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style', 'sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS', 'urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions', 'sapComDocumentSapRfcFunctions'};
        public sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00(String Dpi2Rtrvlastsaveddata,sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbstDatarcrd01 DpistInpt) {
            sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00_element request_x = new sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00_element();
            sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element response_x;
            request_x.Dpi2Rtrvlastsaveddata = Dpi2Rtrvlastsaveddata;
            request_x.DpistInpt = DpistInpt;
            Map<String, sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              '',
              'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',
              'ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00',
              'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',
              'ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response',
              'sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x;
        }
    }
    public class Bapiret2 {
        public String Type_x;
        public String Id;
        public String Number_x;
        public String Message;
        public String LogNo;
        public String LogMsgNo;
        public String MessageV1;
        public String MessageV2;
        public String MessageV3;
        public String MessageV4;
        public String Parameter;
        public Integer Row;
        public String Field;
        public String System_x;
        private String[] Type_x_type_info = new String[]{'Type','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] Id_type_info = new String[]{'Id','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] Number_x_type_info = new String[]{'Number','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] Message_type_info = new String[]{'Message','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] LogNo_type_info = new String[]{'LogNo','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] LogMsgNo_type_info = new String[]{'LogMsgNo','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] MessageV1_type_info = new String[]{'MessageV1','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] MessageV2_type_info = new String[]{'MessageV2','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] MessageV3_type_info = new String[]{'MessageV3','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] MessageV4_type_info = new String[]{'MessageV4','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] Parameter_type_info = new String[]{'Parameter','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] Row_type_info = new String[]{'Row','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] Field_type_info = new String[]{'Field','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] System_x_type_info = new String[]{'System','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style','false','true'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'Type_x','Id','Number_x','Message','LogNo','LogMsgNo','MessageV1','MessageV2','MessageV3','MessageV4','Parameter','Row','Field','System_x'};
    }
    public class ZgssmbssDatarcrd01 {
        public String Cdata;
        private String[] Cdata_type_info = new String[]{'Cdata','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style','false','true'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'Cdata'};
    }
    public class Bapiret2T {
        public sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.Bapiret2[] item;
        private String[] item_type_info = new String[]{'item','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'0','-1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style','false','true'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'item'};
    }
    public class ZgssmbstDatarcrd01 {
        public sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01[] item;
        private String[] item_type_info = new String[]{'item','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'0','-1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style','false','true'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'item'};
    }
    public class ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element {
        public sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.Bapiret2T DpostMssg;
        public sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbstDatarcrd01 DpostOtpt;
        private String[] DpostMssg_type_info = new String[]{'DpostMssg','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] DpostOtpt_type_info = new String[]{'DpostOtpt','urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style','false','true'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'DpostMssg','DpostOtpt'};
    }
}
```

**Controller extension:**

```
    public with sharing class OpenDocumentsController {
    public Boolean displayOpenQuotations {get; set;}
    public string pageSize {get;set;}

    private final Account acct;
    public String CustNo {get;set;}
    public Integer offset { get; set;}
    public Integer NumOf {get;set;}
    public Double TotalAmount {get;set;}


    public List<Quotation> lstQuotations {get;set;}

    private List<String> lstReqData {get;set;}
    private String EventType {get;set;}
    private String InputFields {get;set;}
    private String InputData {get;set;}


   public OpenDocumentsController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        displayOpenQuotations = true;
        pageSize = '5';

        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {        
            List<String> addl = new List<String> {};
            addl.add('accountnumber');
            stdController.addFields(addl);
        }
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        System.debug('acct:'+acct);

        if(CustNo == null) {
            CustNo = acct.AccountNumber; //'1172';
        }
         //offset = 0;
         System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>offset'+offset);
    }       


//Method to get Open Quotations
    public Quotation[] getOpenQuotations() {
        lstReqData = new List<string> {};
        try {
            if(displayOpenQuotations == true && lstQuotations == null) {
                offset = 0;
                sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.Z_GSSMWFM_HNDL_EVNTRQST00 sap1 = new sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.Z_GSSMWFM_HNDL_EVNTRQST00();       
                Map<List<String>,List<List<String>>> mapSAP = new Map<List<String>,List<List<String>>> {};
                sap1.timeout_x = 90000;
                sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbstDatarcrd01 req = new sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbstDatarcrd01();      
                List<List<String>> nlstData = new List<List<String>> {};

                lstQuotations = new List<Quotation> {};

                //DATA-TYPE[.]ZGSEVDST_OPENQTA[.]RESPONSE-TYPE=FULL-SETS;ROW-COUNT=1;[.]VBELN[.]AUDAT[.]KUNNR[.]NAME[.]NETWR[.]WAERK[.]ANGDT[.]BNDDT[.]QUNTITY
                //ZGSEVDST_OPENQTA[.]20000039[.]2014-02-05[.]1172[.]CBD Computer Based Design[.]5145.00[.]USD[.]2014-02-05[.]2014-03-06[.]1 of ETO-A002 , 1 of 100-300 , 1 of GTS-14013

                //populating item values

                String EventType = 'EVENT[.]SFDC-OPEN-QUT-GET[.]VERSION[.]0[.]RESPONSE-TYPE[.]FULL-SETS';
                String InputFields = 'SDCAS_T_CUSTLIST[.]'+CustNo;
                String InputData = 'ZGSEVDST_SISINFOINPU[.]'+CustNo;
                lstReqData.add(EventType);
                lstReqData.add(InputFields);
                lstReqData.add(InputData);
                req.item = LoadRequestData(lstReqData);
                sap1.timeout_x = 90000;
                sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element ret =  sap1.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00('',req);
            }
        }Catch(Exception e) {
            Apexpages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(Apexpages.Severity.FATAL,'Oops, please try again!!');
            Apexpages.addMessage(msg);
        }
        return lstQuotations;

    }


   public void nextPage() {
   }

   public void previousPage() {
       offset = Math.max(0, offset - 5);
   }

   public void lastPage() {

   }

   public void firstPage() {
       offset = 0;
   }

/*
Wrapper for Open Quotations

Doc Number  Doc Date    Customer Number Customer Name   Amount  CURRENCY    VALID FROM DATE VALID TO DATE   PRODUCTS
Quotation # Quotation Date

[.]AUDAT[.]KUNNR[.]NAME[.]NETWR[.]WAERK[.]ANGDT[.]BNDDT[.]QUNTITY   
*/
 public class Quotation{
        public String DocNumber{get; set;} //VBELN
        public String DocDate{get; set;} //AUDAT
        public String CustomerNumber{get; set;} //KUNRG
        public String CustomerName {get;set;} //NAME
        public String Amount{get; set;} //NETWR    
        public String Curren{get; set;} //WAERK
        public String ValidFromDt{get;set;} //ANGDT
        public String ValidToDt{get;set;} //BNDDT
        public String Product{get;set;} //QUNTITY

    }

   public static List<sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01> LoadRequestData(List<String> lstInput) {
        List<sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01> itm = new List<sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01>();

        //populating item values
        sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01 s1 = new sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01();
        s1.Cdata = 'DEVICE-ID:160000000000000:DEVICE-TYPE:SFDC-CLIENT:APPLICATION-ID:SFDC-SALES';
        itm.add(s1);

        sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01 s2 = new sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01();       
        s2.Cdata = 'NOTATION:ZML:VERSION:0:DELIMITER:[.]';
        itm.add(s2);

        for(String s: lstInput) {
            sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01 s3 = new sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01();
            s3.Cdata = s;
            itm.add(s3);
        }       
        System.debug('item values:'+itm);
        return itm;

    }

    //Method to parse the response from the webservice call
    public static Map<List<String>,List<List<String>>> ParseMultipleResponse(sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element ret) {
        System.debug('Inside ParseMultipleResponse');
        List<String> lstHeader = new List<String> {};
        List<String> lstData = new List<String> {};
        List<List<String>> nlstData = new List<List<String>> {};
        Map<List<String>,List<List<String>>> mapSAP = new Map<List<String>,List<List<String>>> {};
        System.debug('response value 1:'+ret.DpostMssg.item);
        System.debug('response value 2:'+ret.DpostOtpt.item);

        //if(ret.DpostMssg.item.isEmpty()) {
            Integer cnt = 0;

            for(sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01 r: ret.DpostOtpt.item) {
                System.debug('cdata value:'+r.Cdata);
                if(cnt == 2) {
                    lstHeader = r.Cdata.split('\\[.]');
                }

                if(cnt >= 3) {
                    lstData = r.Cdata.split('\\[.]');
                    nlstData.add(lstData);
                }
                cnt ++;
            }

            System.debug('lstHeader:'+lstHeader);
            System.debug('lstData:'+lstData);
            System.debug('nlstData:'+nlstData);

        mapSAP.put(lstHeader,nlstData);

        //}
        //System.debug('mapSAP:'+mapSAP);
        return mapSAP;      
    }

    public static String FormatDate(String s) {
        if(s != null || s!= '') {
            String[] dt = s.split('-');
            return dt[1]+'-'+dt[2]+'-'+dt[0];
        } else {
            return '';
        }

    }


    public static Boolean isCurrentMonthYear(String s) {
        if(s!= null && s!= '') {
            String[] dt = s.split('-');
            if(Date.today().month() == Integer.valueOf(dt[1]) && String.valueOf(Date.today().year()) == dt[0]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



}
```

**WebserviceMockImpl class:**

```
    @isTest
global class WebServiceMockImpl implements WebServiceMock {
   global void doInvoke(
           Object stub,
           Object request,
           Map<String, Object> response,
           String endpoint,
           String soapAction,
           String requestName,
           String responseNS,
           String responseName,
           String responseType) {

        sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.Z_GSSMWFM_HNDL_EVNTRQST00 sap1 = new sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.Z_GSSMWFM_HNDL_EVNTRQST00();       
        sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbstDatarcrd01 req = new sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbstDatarcrd01();      

        sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element ret =  sap1.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00('',req);

        sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01 zg = new sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01();
        //zg.Cdata = 'test';

        sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbstDatarcrd01 str = new sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbstDatarcrd01();

        zg.Cdata = 'DATA-TYPE[.]ZGSEVDST_MATPRICE[.]RESPONSE-TYPE=FULL-SETS;ROW-COUNT=1;[.]KUNNR[.]MATNR[.]KBETR[.]KONWA';
        str.item.add(zg);
        zg.Cdata = 'ZGSEVDST_MATPRICE[.][.]100-100[.]85.00[.]USD';
        str.item.add(zg);



        //sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbssDatarcrd01[] item;
        //item.add(zg);

        //req.item = zg;
        ret.DpostOtpt = str;
        System.debug('return from test:'+ret);
        response.put('response_x', ret.DpostOtpt); 
   }
}
```

**Test class for the controller:**

```
   @isTest

public with sharing class testOpenDocumentsController {
    public static testMethod void testOpenDocuments() {


        Account a = new Account(Name='Tester', AccountNumber='1172');
        insert a;

        Test.startTest();

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(a);
        OpenDocumentsController OD = new OpenDocumentsController(sc);
        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new WebServiceMockImpl()); 
        OD.getOpenQuotations();

        Test.stopTest();
        //System.assertEquals(e.acct, a);
    }

}
```

**Issue:**

> ```
> System.LimitException: Too many callouts: 11
> ```

Comment: total stab in the dark: does the problem persist if you Disable Parallel Apex Testing ?

Comment: Thanks @SamuelDeRycke. Yes, i already disabled that option.But this issue is lingering for more than a day now...

Comment: A first step would be to add more debug output in the logic before the callout code (assuming the current debug log doesn't revealed anything on careful examination).

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the callout is not in a loop, or within a trigger(s)?

Comment: OR that other callouts are not being executed by triggers on your objects/managed packages?

Comment: Thanks, @KeithC. As per your advice i am going take the classes (controller, vfpage, utility class, test class that are related to this issue) to another dev org to isolate and will add more debug statements to find the source of issue.

Comment: @KeithC i have updated the post with all the source code.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke i have posted all the source code here

Comment: @AlexTennant i have updated the post with all the source code related to this issue

Comment: Can you try set "Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new WebServiceMockImpl()); " just after Test.startTest() ? - without analzying your entire code base that's the first thing that I noticed - though not sure how that could lead to hitting the limit.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Thanks for looking into this issue. It is still throwing the same issue Too many callouts.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke all the above code will work in any org without any need for additional components like custom fields or objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I must admit I don't fully know how your mock implementation should look like, but I do think I understand what's going wrong in your version.

A mockservice should "simply" (may not be simple at all) return a response as your service callout is intended to respond. **The mockservice class, is not intended to make any call outs (or attempts) - as this would trigger a recursive cycle in a test context where the mockservice is set.**

Your mock service contains the line:

```
sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element ret =  sap1.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00('',req);
```

This is attempting to perform the webcall out ..

```
 public sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00(String Dpi2Rtrvlastsaveddata, sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbstDatarcrd01 DpistInpt) {
            sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00_element request_x = new sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00_element();
            sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element response_x;
            request_x.Dpi2Rtrvlastsaveddata = Dpi2Rtrvlastsaveddata;
            request_x.DpistInpt = DpistInpt;
            Map < String, sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element > response_map_x = new Map < String, sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element > ();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[] {
                    endpoint_x,
                        '',
                        'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',
                        'ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00',
                        'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',
                        'ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response',
                        'sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element'
                }
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x;
        }
```

which in a test context where this mockservice is set will lauch a new mock instance, which will launch a new webcall out , which will launch a new mock instance, which will launch a new ... etc untill you hit the 11 call outs governor limit.

**Update:**
As the webcall method returns you an `ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element` object, your `WebServiceMockImpl.doInvoke()` method should be **COMPOSING** such a record and add it to the response map.

```
public class ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element {
        public sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.Bapiret2T DpostMssg;
        public sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbstDatarcrd01 DpostOtpt;
        private String[] DpostMssg_type_info = new String[] {'DpostMssg', 'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style', null, '1', '1', 'false'};
        private String[] DpostOtpt_type_info = new String[] {'DpostOtpt', 'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style', null, '1', '1', 'false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[] {'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style', 'false', 'true'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[] {'DpostMssg', 'DpostOtpt'};
    }
```

As only the `DpostMssg` and  `DpostOtpt` fields aren't populated, I **guess** that you should try to put some content in there. I would try to get some real responses from the webservice, either by debugging through apex (not in test mode) or using a tool like SOAPUI. This so that you know what response data from this webservice actually looks like, and so that you can copy a response with content required for your tests in your mockservice.